# Sliding menu DrawerLayout in xml

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

hello everyone I'm newbie and want to make a sliding menu with toolbar.  here my code xml toolbar at MainActivity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/headerIconLeft"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/headerIconRight"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/headerBack"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/headerIconLeft"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_back" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/headerMenu"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/headerIconLeft"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_menu" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_update"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/headerIconRight"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Update"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/headerIconRight"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headerTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/headerIconRight"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/headerIconLeft"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Title"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

but when i change the parent layout to DrawerLayout it's mess out

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/headerIconLeft"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/headerIconRight"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/headerBack"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/headerIconLeft"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_back" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/headerMenu"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/headerIconLeft"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_menu" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_update"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/headerIconRight"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Update"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_delete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/headerIconRight"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Delete"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/headerTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/headerIconRight"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/headerIconLeft"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here are some images :

- [drawerlayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0gHv.png)
- [without drawerlayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQP2Z.png)